# iOS 16.0 - PHPicker issue with PHPickerConfiguration config.selection = .people

Tags: ios, swift, phpickerviewcontroller, phpicker

I'm facing issues on 16.0 using `PHPickerViewController` with `PHPickerConfiguration` `config.selection = .people`.  The PHPicker screen shows an error "Unable to Load Photos". Xcode 14.0.1.

```
import UIKit
import PhotosUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showPicker()
    }

    private func showPicker() {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
        config.filter = .images
        config.selection = .people
        config.selectionLimit = 10
        let vc = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        vc.delegate = self
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension ViewController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {

    }
}
```

Console log:

`[Picker] Showing picker unavailable UI (reason: crashed) with error: (null)  viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}`

If I comment that line (`config.selection = .people`) it works perfect.

My question is: Has anyone gone through this? know how to fix it?